# Database command to delete users according to time definitions

Tags: mysql

Users for whom the registration date (timestamp) is older than today-1day and fulfills the condition should be deleted.

Example:
User 1 to 3 have RegDate: 11/21/2022 - HH:MM
User 4 have RegDate: 11/18/2022 - HH:MM
a) RegDate = 11/18/2022 (is stored in the database as a timestamp)
b) Today is 11/22/2022 - 1 day = 11/21/2022 = HH:MM

Since the registration date is before 11/21/2002 and the condition of user 4 is met, he should be deleted.

My attempt:

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE (regdate < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - '86400')) AND hideemail = '1'");
```

oder

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE (datediff(now(), `regdate`) >= 1) AND hideemail = '1'");
```

Regardless of whether I choose < or >, users 1-3 are always deleted but user 4 is not.
The aim should be that only user 4 is deleted and users 1 to 3 are not.

I'm defining something wrong.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to delete users registered before 2022-11-21 (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY) or before 2022-11-21 13:10:17 (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "users WHERE (regdate < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND hideemail = 1");
```

or

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "users WHERE (regdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND hideemail = 1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. which I can understand as absolutely logical. I've implemented it now, but no matter how I define it [< or >, as well as with and without brackets] only users 1-3 are deleted, although only user 4 should actually be deleted. What can be the cause of this misconduct?

Comment: @Fontane Please add your `CREATE TABLE` statement and the surrounding code, as based on the information currently provided, this would work as requested. Here's a simple [<dbfiddle>](https://dbfiddle.uk/va1RGpS3) to demonstrate.